# « Got it » en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, interjections

Comment puis-je exprimer l'anglais « *got it* » en français ? Est-ce vraiment « je comprends » ?

Google Translate ne me donne pas une bonne explication, ni Internet.

---

*English version*

How can I say "got it" in french? It's really "je comprends"?

Google Translate doesn't give me a good explanation, nor the internet at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

“*Je comprends*” has the same meaning, but is in my opinion somewhat more formal than “got it”. If you want to keep the general tone, “*Compris*” might be a better translation.

Answer (score 11):

You might hear *"Pigé !"* for *"Got it !"* in informal situations.

Answer (score 5):

*C'est compris* keeps the familiar tone of *got it*. Likewise, it can be used both as an assertion and as an interrogative.

Answer (score 2):

People in France will also say 'ok!', English has really permeated the country by now.
But you can say 'compris!' as well, or 'd'accord' if you are agreeing on statement.

Answer (score 0):

*Got it!* is incorrect in English and as said above means “j'ai compris”. Now you may want to keep the meaning and the incorrectness, for instance in a translation of a book. Then *Pigé !* is excellent.